# Difference among the following structures: not only X but also Y, not only X but Y, not only X, also Y

Tags: meaning-in-context, parallelism

I realize that there are a few threads on this forum dedicated to covering the parallelism aspect of 'not only X but also Y', so this post could possibly be added to an existing thread. I would like to apologize in advance if there is an already existing thread related to this topic - the only reason I am posting this query in a new thread is that I could not find an existing thread related to this slightly(?) nuanced difference among these three constructions.

Is there any difference among the following structures:

- Not only X but also Y
- Not only X also Y (without the 'but')
- Not only X but Y (without the 'also')

I tried searching long and hard for this split, but couldn't find anything concrete; it would be greatly helpful if you could explain whether there is any difference among the 3 structures (from a meaning perspective) or whether they are interchangeable?

Comment: It's not usually very idiomatic to omit either of the words ***but also*** in a *"**not only**"* construction, so I'd advise you not to do it yourself. But it never makes any difference to the meaning.

Comment: To add to @FumbleFingers, #3 is clunky, but #2 is going to look like an omitted word / typo.

Comment: We need some sample sentences. #3 could appear to be valid in some constructions: "I'm not only handsome but modest as well"—but that's really cheating because "as well" is just replacing "also" synonymously, and the syntax is re-ordered. We could do without both "but" and "also" in "Not only did I make you a sandwich, I ate it," but you can't try that stunt with some other constructions.

Comment: Okay, so some sample sentences should help in terms of the context. I read, while preparing for the GMAT, that the 'also' could be redundant in the following context:

There are Indians not only in Gujarat, but in India (Using the 'also' or 'as well' would be considered redundant here, since Gujarat is a part of India).

Is it only when the 'X' is a subset of 'Y' that we can use the 'not only' without an 'also' in the second half?
I have also come to realize that 'not only X but also Y' is another way of saying 'Y as well as X' - is there any corresponding structure for the others? Thanks

Comment: Similarly, this sentence is something that has been bothering me:

"As criminal activity on the Internet becomes more and more sophisticated, not only are thieves able to divert cash from company bank accounts, they can also pilfer valuable information such as business development strategies, new product specifications, and contract bidding plans, and sell the data to competitors"

As we can see here, the 'also' is used without a corresponding 'but', and is the correct answer. So my question is, would there have been any meaning differences if I were to add the 'but' before the 'also' here

Comment: Once again, thank you @AndyBonner, FumbleFingers, and jimm101 for all your help :-)

Comment: To clarify, I would like to understand if there are any *meaning* differences among these 3 structures:

Not only is he a bad man, he is also a bad person
Not only is he a bad man, but he is also a bad person
Not only is he a bad man, but he is a bad person

I know that Grammarly recommends that I add in the 'but' in the first sentence, possibly to prevent it from becoming a run-on. But it doesn't seem to me that the first half is an independent clause, so the conjunction should not be mandatory - am I correct in my thought process?

Please advise.

Comment: 1) I encourage you to edit the original question to add any clarifications there, not just in comments, for the sake of future viewers (it might even narrow the question to the point that some of these comments could be valid *answers*!) 2) The Gujarat example is intriguing, but I'd argue it's actually a slightly different usage. I'd argue that, there, "only" is taking its own full meaning, not just as a part of the phrase "not only." In other words, it means "not in Gujarat alone." 3) The "criminal activity" sentence commits some slight non-parallel construction (perhaps forgivable?). ...

Comment: ... 4) but it shows that some constructions need these helping words and some don't. To your central question of "does it change the meaning," **no**. All of the constructions under discussion here accomplish the same Venn-diagram meaning: "[Subset] is true, and so is [superset]!" 5) *Not only is he a bad man, but he is a bad person* —I would argue you should actually leave "but" out of this construction. Or save the repetition of the verb: "He is not only a bad man but a bad person."

Comment: Thank you so much @AndyBonner. I have noted your point regarding adding 'edits' in the original question. I was unaware of this as this is my first post on this platform, but I can see how it could lead to confusion. I am sorry for the error and will keep this in mind when I make future posts.

Thank you so much for resolving my query. I will go through your responses in detail and absorb them as best as I can, but from what (ever much) I have currently understood, you have resolved my doubts. Thank you once again!

Comment: The third construction can be used if Y intensifies X, for example "not only cold, but freezing". Doing this backwards as in "not only freezing, but quite chilly" is usually a joke.

Comment: I feel this is off-topic... the OP has already seen answers on the topic, and there doesn't seem to be a question except "what about these"? Posting some made-up sentences that are contrary to what they have already read, and asking "are they correct"  is definitely off-topic.

Comment: Dear @Astralbee - the sentences are not made up, and I wanted to understand the meaning differences among the 3 structures. I had not come across a unifying thread addressing this issue in detail, but if there exists such a thread that I may have overlooked, I would request you to point me to the thread. Seeing answers on a 'topic', and having a 'specific query' are two entirely things. The question was also much more than 'what about these?' - if you read carefully, it was about the meaning differences within the structures. Distorting it to a strawman doesn't help.

Comment: It was no strawman, I was just scrutinising your question in light of the site rules. You say you've searched hard and found nothing about some sentences that you've written wrongly. Well, that shouldn't be a surprise. That's like saying "I just made up the word 'boody' and I can't find it in the dictionary".

Comment: @Astralbee The question was not about the sentences but about the differences among the three structures. I added the sentences because the comments asked for context - the query was about the overall structure. Comparing a valid grammatical construct to a nonsensical word as 'boody' undermines your argument. If you have nothing useful to add, may I please request you to not be discouraging to new members? I am not sure what your comments have added to the discussion, except that it may be a violation of a site rule. Yet I am not sure how it violates the rules, and a PM would've been better.

Comment: Thank you @Peter. Yes, it makes sense now as to why the 'also' would be slightly redundant in such cases. I suppose the idea is that the 'not only X but also Y' would be needed if X and Y are two different entities rather than Y being an intensification of X?